# Fonts in CSS3 - what a painful experience

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I would like to add a non standard font (specifically [Quicksand](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand)) in a web page. What I do in my CSS sheet is the classic (I assume it's classic):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: QuicksandLight;
    src: url('fonts/Quicksand_Light.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

Now, when I render the page the font is Quicksand... But it's no Light. Is there a way to be sure my font will be well rendered?

**Note** on Chrome at least the non-Light rendering of Quicksand is fine, in Firefox it's terrible, in Opera it hurts my heart.

Comment: Does it look different on your site than it does on that page?

Comment: @isherwood It renders the same through all "my website" (quoted because it still has just one page).

Comment: Check this out http://css-tricks.com/beefing-up-dull-text-in-webkit/

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: @isherwood then I didn't understand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Does the font on your site appear the same as it does on the page you linked?

Comment: @isherwood Oh, yeah I'm sorry, you meant the [Quicksand](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand) page. No, my font looks exactly like Quicksand **non**-Light but it's Quicksand **Light**. Actually that's on Chrome, because on Opera/Firefox it looks like a squashed Quicksand.

Comment: Just curious (and, I don't intend this to be an answer, that's why I'm putting it as a comment): why aren't you using one of the FontSquirrel-generated @font-face kits for this? They give you all the CSS code and font files you need to get things going easily.

Comment: @djangodude yesterday I managed to sleep thanks to FontSquirrel actually :) I discovered that site only yesterday